# Сократить путь

Tags: php

Привет. У меня есть путь до папки вида "/tmp/../tmp/../uploads/../uploads".
Этот путь можно записать так: "/uploads"
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какая-нибудь функция на PHP, которая "обрезает" путь?

Comment: Никита, распишите подробнее или решение Photon Вас устраивает?

Comment: Вполне, но я бы не отказался посмотреть на другое решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
realpath('/tmp/../tmp/../uploads/../uploads');
```